# Multicollinearity Issue in SEM model

Tags: multicollinearity, structural-equation-modeling

In our model we are getting multicollinearity issues. But the problem is that we can't combined the variables or drop certain variables to get rid of multicollinearity.

Model Structure:

My Model looks like the following structure. This structure is taken from the following website:

http://www.smallwaters.com/whitepapers/marketing/

[image]

The problem is there's correlation between factors "Fashion Consciousness" and "Materialism". But we want to keep both these factors. That's why std is coming really high.

My question is how can I deal with multicollinearity in SEM model apart from above options.

Also, if somebody can give me some references on SEM explaining using matrix methods. Most of the reference I read have explained things with software results.

I'm looking for materials like the one in the following link:

http://openmx.psyc.virginia.edu/thread/397

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more. Collinearity problems that mean that the model won't converge, that the standard errors are too high, or that you don't like the estimates?

Comment: Thanks Jerry for your comment. I've updated my question. Hope this will help.

Comment: I initially thought that Inclination to purchase is a second-level latent variable. From the website you link to it becomes apparent that it is just another latent variable without indicators shown in the figure. As to solution, wouldn't allowing your two predictors to covary alleviate the issue?

Comment: If they're correlated, they're correlated. That's just the way it is. If you want to get the effect of each, controlling for the other, you have to have them both there. The fact that they're correlated means you've got more uncertainty around the estimate, and hence a larger standard error.

Comment: But why don't you want to combine them? Also, what's the model fit like.

Comment: @Maxim: Thanks for your reply. No. I didn't tried two predictors to covary. But I'll surely try it.  @ Jeremy: Thanks Jeremy! If there's multicollinearity, then beta value is not stable. So can't use those beta for any further analysis. And we can't 2 factors (here "Fashion consciousness" and "Materialism") as want to keep both of them.